# NullReferenceException was caught...?

Tags: c#, foreach

After running foreach loop. I am getting NullReferenceException on second item, because query result is null. But I have more item to use on same query and get the result on richTextBox1. so have can I continue the foreach loop if there is any null result.

```
foreach (string Items in listBox4.Items)
{
    using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand("select REGEXP_REPLACE(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','" + Items + "'),('" + txtSrcUserID.Text + "...'),'', 1, 0, 'i') from dual", conn1))                           
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString() + ";");
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }                                                      
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is dangerous programming. You really should be checking for the `null`. Assuming your loop will get bigger.. I would include a `continue` and make it a bit more obvious what it is you're doing for readability. Omit the `continue` if you don't need it.

```
var result = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar();

if (result != null) {
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    richTextBox1.AppendText(result.ToString() + ";");
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
else {
    continue;
}

// any other code here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString()` to `(crtCommand.ExecuteScalar() ?? string.Empty).ToString()`.  This is logically equivalent to:

```
  object dbResult = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar();
  if(dbResult == null) 
  {
     richTextBox1.AppendText(";");
  }
  else
  {
     richTextBox1.AppendText(dbResult.ToString() + ";");
  }
```

If you want to completely ignore a null result instead of treating it as an empty string, use @SimonWhitehead's code

Comment: You might want to explain the ?? operator.

Comment: I came from PHP to C#, I had never encountered the ?? operator until recently, so I don't assume everybody has.